# Tableau Data Extract using AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-athena

I have a field reported_date defined as STRING data type in the Athena catalog and I marked it as Date in Tableau. But when I try to do the incremental extract using the reported_date field, I am getting an "Incorrect Data Type" error. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? One option that I am trying is to change the data type to date and check if it works.[image: Incorrect Data Type Error]

The live connection works perfectly fine, but only extract is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing if it is a string in Athena, it will come in as a string in the extract refresh. Casting to date so it is a Date by the time it hits Tableau should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't caste to date before data hits Tableu , I ended up changing the data type in Athena to Date and it worked. overall Extraction of about 2 Million took about 30 minutes.